# Libreoffice Calc won't show/hide selected rows/cols

Tags: libreoffice

Why can I not show/hide rows or columns in Ubuntu's LibreOffice?

The menus shown in the tutorial aren't there: http://guide2office.com/602/faq-how-to-hide-columns-in-openoffice-org-calc-show-hide/

Comment: Are you right-clicking on the row/column header after selecting the row/column to hide?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you can, when the spreadsheet is in EDIT mode. When you download .ods from a Google spreadsheet it is read-only by default when you open it. (It's odd that in this case, the only right click row menu items are copy, and PASTE.)

Dragging the resizer with multiple rows selected works, or you can just click the "edit" button in toolbar.